# Twig generate <td> in <tr> based on an integer value

Tags: php, html, for-loop, twig, opencart-3

search over this in google and looked the official docs of twig, didn't find an answer,

I have this

```
  $data['count'] = $count;//6
```

in my php code,
I want to generate td as much as the $beltCount in the twig file I tried this but it didn't work:

```
{% for i in count%}
  <td> {{ i }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Should I do this in a different way? I didn't find a syntax for this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer 6 isn't enumerable, it's just a number.

You can however use `range(1, count)` or, as stated [Teneff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637367/teneff) in comments, the range operator `1..count` to create an enumerable from 1 to 6 (or whatever value is in `count`) :

```
{% for i in range(1, count) %}
  <td> {{ i }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

---

```
{% for i in 1..count %}
  <td> {{ i }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/zcoji4)

You will find more infos in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/functions/range.html)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that twig also supports a range operator (`..`). `{% for i in 1..count}`

Comment: @Teneff I wasn't sure if some variables could be used with the range operator

Comment: Yep, they can. [Here's an example](https://twigfiddle.com/zcoji4)

Comment: @Teneff I tried it but didn't work because I missed something else, so I thought it won't work, thank you very much